# sparql and query in group of multiple predicates

Tags: sparql

I did not get the right sentence to ask the question.
I would like to explain my problem using a sample data.

let's say the triples are as below.

```
@prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> .
@prefix xs: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix p0: <http://www.mlacustom.com#> .
@prefix p2: <http://www.mla.com/term/> .
_:bnode7021016689601753065 p0:lastModifiedDateTime "2018-09-14T12:55:38"^^<xsd:dateTime> ;
                           p0:lastModifiedUser "admin"^^xs:string .
<http://www.mla.com/name/4204078359> p0:hasClassingFacet "http://www.mla.com/facet/RA"^^xs:string ;
                                     p0:type "Normal"^^xs:string ;
                                     p0:classification _:bnode3452184423513029143 ,
                                                       _:bnode6827572371999795686 ;
                                     p0:recordType "Name"^^xs:string ;
                                     p0:recordNumber "4204078359"^^xs:string ;
                                     p0:stdDescriptor "classification111111"^^xs:string ;
                                     p0:establishedBy "admin"^^xs:string ;
                                     skos:prefLabel "classification111111"^^xs:string ;
                                     p0:createdBy "admin"^^xs:string ;
                                     a skos:Concept ;
                                     p0:createdDate "2018-09-14T12:55:38"^^<xsd:dateTime> ;
                                     p0:establishedDate "2018-09-14T12:55:38"^^<xsd:dateTime> ;
                                     p0:hasRAsubFacet "http://www.mla.com/subfacet/classing-subject-authors"^^xs:string ;
                                     p0:lastModifiedDate "2018-09-14T12:55:38"^^<xsd:dateTime> ;
                                     p0:lastModifiedDetails _:bnode7021016689601753065 ;
                                     p0:isProblematic "N,N"^^xs:string ;
                                     p0:lastModifiedBy "admin"^^xs:string ;
                                     p0:status "established"^^xs:string .
_:bnode3452184423513029143 p0:literature p2:1513 ;
                           p0:timePeriod p2:1005 ;
                           p0:language p2:3199 .
_:bnode6827572371999795686 p0:literature p2:11307 ;
                           p0:timePeriod p2:1009 ;
                           p0:language p2:31 .
```

please have a look at the `p0:classification` it has two blank nodes and both the blank nodes has triples with `p0:literature, p0:timePeriod, p0:language`

Now I want to write a SPARQL query where

```
(
   (p0:literature is p2:1513 AND  p0:timePeriod is p2:1005) AND 
   (p0:literature is p2:11307 AND p0:timePeriod is p2:1009)
)
```

As per the above scenario it should return me the `http://www.mla.com/name/4204078359` subject

Classification can have any number of blank nodes.

Comment: you have the data in Turtle syntax here. SPARQL is really simple, as it also supports Turtle syntax. that means, you have the structure, just  (re)use the part you're interested in and replace the resources in each triple you're interested in by a variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one of the solutions. It is possible to find many different queries. This one is explicit.

```
SELECT ?s WHERE {
    ?s p0:classification ?o1 .
    ?s p0:classification ?o2 .

    ?o1 p0:literature p2:1513 ;
        p0:timePeriod p2:1005 .

    ?o2 p0:literature p2:11307 ;
        p0:timePeriod p2:1009 .
}
```