# How to select a property according to a condition in RDF

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, semantic-web, rdfs

In the following RDF sample, I would like to get a value of one of properties according to a condition.
The condition is below:

- If a value of property `referProperty` is `"ex:sender"`, then I get a value of property `ex:sender`.
- If a value of property `referProperty` is `"ex:reciever"`, then I get a value of property `ex:reciever`.

```
@prefix ex: <http://www.example.org#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

ex:mail1
  ex:sender "John"^^xsd:string ;
  ex:receiver "Bill"^^xsd:string ;
  ex:paymentType ex:paymentType1 .

ex:mail2
  ex:sender "Jack"^^xsd:string ;
  ex:receiver "Tom"^^xsd:string ;
  ex:paymentType ex:paymentType2 .

ex:paymentType1
  ex:paymentTypeDescription "PREPAID"^^xsd:string ;
  ex:referProperty "ex:sender"^^xsd:string .

ex:paymentType2
  ex:paymentTypeDescription "COLLECT"^^xsd:string ;
  ex:referProperty "ex:receiver"^^xsd:string .
```

Sparql to get a value is below:

```
PREFIX ex:<http://ww....ex#>
SELECT ?mail ?refProp ?payer
WHERE
{
    {
        SELECT ?mail ?refProp
        WHERE
        {
            ?mail ex:paymentType / ex:referProperty ?refProp.
        }
    }
    ?mail ?refProp ?payer.
}
```

It is possible to get a value by the Sparql. But I question that the way using the above RDF sample and Sparql is irregular, because it seems to extends outside first-order predicate logic.
Using a value which was gotten from literal node as a variable to search a property is irregular. In theory, property”ex:referProperty” should be defined in RDFS.
Do you think so? If you think so, teach me a regular way which includes right RDF and right Sparql.

Comment: I don't get it...what is the expected result given the sample data? and what means *" Using a value which was gotten from literal node as a variable to search a property is irregular."*? and what do you want to say by *"In theory, property”ex:referProperty” should be defined in RDFS."*?

Comment: Why not simply use the IRI of the property instead if a literal? E.g. 'ex:referProperty ex:sender .' instead of 'ex:referProperty "ex:sender"^^xsd:string .'

Comment: Answers may also be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52368573/sparql-and-query-in-group-of-multiple-predicates/52368723#52368723

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

One can transform URIs to strings and vice versa using [`STR()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-str), [`IRI()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-iri) and [`REPLACE()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-replace):

```sql
PREFIX ex: <http://www.example.org#>
SELECT ?mail ?str ?payer {
   ?mail ?p ?payer; ex:paymentType/ex:referProperty ?str.
   FILTER (replace(str(?p), str(ex:), "ex:") = ?str)
}
```

or

```sql
PREFIX ex: <http://www.example.org#>
SELECT ?mail ?str ?payer {
   ?mail ?p ?payer; ex:paymentType/ex:referProperty ?str.
   FILTER (URI(replace(?str, "ex:", str(ex:))) = ?p)
}
```

**Option 2**

You can implement your conditions using [`BIND`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#bind) and [`IF`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-if):

```sql
PREFIX ex: <http://www.example.org#>
SELECT ?mail ?str ?payer {
   ?mail ex:paymentType/ex:referProperty ?str.
   BIND (IF(?str = "ex:sender", ex:sender, ex:receiver) AS ?p)
   ?mail ?p ?payer.
}
```

**Option 3**

Use [`VALUES`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data):

```sql
PREFIX ex: <http://www.example.org#>
SELECT ?mail ?str ?payer {
    VALUES (?str ?uri) {("ex:sender" ex:sender) ("ex:receiver" ex:receiver)}
    ?mail ?uri ?payer; ex:paymentType/ex:referProperty ?str.
}
```

**Option 4**

As [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52398268/how-to-select-a-property-according-to-a-condition-in-rdf/52405983#comment91743085_52398268) by Damyan Ognyanov, you could use URIs instead of strings in your reference data, i. e. `ex:sender` instead of `"ex:sender"` etc. Then your query will be simply the following:

```sql
PREFIX ex: <http://www.example.org#>
SELECT ?mail ?str ?payer {
    ?mail ?uri ?payer; ex:paymentType/ex:referProperty ?uri.
}
```

**Update**

From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52398268/how-to-select-a-property-according-to-a-condition-in-rdf/52405983#comment91777856_52405983):

> Isn’t using `ex:sender` as property and object in one RDF contradiction? Using `ex:sender` as URI in RDF makes the border between RDF an RDFS dubious.

From [RDF 1.1 Concepts and Abstract Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#section-triples):

> The set of **nodes** of an RDF graph is the set of subjects and objects of triples in the graph.
>   It is possible for a predicate IRI to also occur as a node in the same graph.

In RDF, "properties" (or rather their "types")  are first-class objects.
RDFS is rather a vocabulary (which introduces e. g. the notion of `rdf:Property`) than a schema.
There is no clear distinction between "ABox" and "TBox" in RDF.

Comment: Thank you for your teaching me good Sparql. My query will become simple by your idea. However, my question is not solved. The core of my question is expressed in the words” it seems to extends outside first-order predicate logic”. I am thinking in the following way.

Comment: -`Ex:sender` as URI is positioned as property in `ex:mail1 ex:sender "John"^^xsd:string` and it is positioned as object in `ex:paymentType1 ex:referProperty ex:receiver`, but a property is able to be positioned as a subject or an object only in RDFS. Isn’t using `ex:sender` as property and object in one RDF contradiction? Using `ex:sender` as URI in RDF makes the border between RDF an RDFS dubious. Using `"ex:sender"` as string also has a similar problem.

Comment: There is nothing in RDF standarts that forbids using an URI as a subject or object of a triple when it is also used as a predicate. Even one of the very few RDF entailments implies that if a :p is used as predicate, then (:p rdf:type rdf:Propery). See second example from section 8.1.1 from https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-rdf11-mt-20140225/#patterns-of-rdf-entailment-informative.

Comment: Thank you very much. I exactly understood. I read second example from section 8.1.1 of RDF 1.1 Semantics. My question cleared.

Comment: @HisashiSakai, perhaps you just need section 3.1 of RDF concepts: "*It is possible for a predicate IRI to also occur as a node in the same graph.*" I've updated my answer.